# Magento 2: how to set grid getRowUrl via the uiComponent

Tags: magento2, module, grid, magento-2.0, uicomponent

In my current Magento 2 module developement, I currently have the following code in my `Grid.php` file:

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    if ($id = $row->getMageProd()) {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'catalog/product/edit',
            ['id' => $id]
        );
    } else {
        return parent::getRowUrl($row);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can implement such thing via my `ui_component` file ?

Comment: why do you need a row url in the ui component? In the grid approach, the result of `getGridUrl` would determine the url where you are redirected when clicking on the row. The new ui component approach, when clicking a row, you either enter in the inline edit mode or nothing happens.

Comment: @Marius the idea is that entities are linked to products. Based on the `mage_prod` attribute, people should be able to access the product edit page by clicking the row.

Comment: you can add an `actions` column with an edit link at the end of the grid. Would that fit your needs?

Comment: @Marius yes when I asked the question, I felt like that was the only solution that could be done via uiComponents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a column at the end of the grid of type `Action`.
Something like this:
Inside the tag `<columns>` add this at the end

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="[Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\[Endity]Actions">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">[pk_id]</item>
            <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">[param_used_in_get]</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</actionsColumn>
```

then create the class `[Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\[Entity]Actions`.

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
class [Entity]Actions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    const URL_PATH_EDIT = '[module]/[entity]/edit';

    /**
     * URL builder
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item['mage_prod'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'edit' => [
                            'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                                [
                                    '[get_var]' => $item['[pk]_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit')
                        ],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: I add same code in magento 2.1.7 but it's display edit link in grid i want grid row url without edit column.

Comment: @himansu the ui-components grids don't work as the classical grids (with blocks). Clicking on the row does not send you to the edit page of that entity.

Comment: @Marius what is the 'urlEntityParamName'? should that be the same as URL_PATH_EDIT?

Comment: @Marius it is possible - please see Product Grid (my answer below also)

Answer (score 2):

Analog getRowAction 
actions column must exist and must have 'edit' action

```
<columns name="xxx_listing_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xxx_listing.xxx_listing.xxx_listing_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the product grid as example.
So you need add **columns.settings** and **actionsColumn** for your component xml file

```
...
    <columns name="entity_columns">
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">component_name.component_name.entity_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
.....
       <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\News\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\NewsActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">news_id</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">news_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
...
```

Also you need add styles for cursor (in your _module.less)

```
    .vendor_name-index-index {
    .admin__data-grid-wrap {
        .data-row {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
      }
   }
```